# apache rewrite rule to file

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, mod-alias

[Ubuntu14/Apache2.4]
I would like to use a Rewrite rule to a file out of DocumentRoot:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  (.*).abc /etc/myproject/myfile.php?File=$1.abc [NC,L]
```

But, I can't because Apache search the file in DocumentRoot folder where it does not exists.

So I can use AliasMatch:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  (.*).abc /myfile.php?File=$1.abc [NC,L]
AliasMatch   /myfile.php /etc/myproject/myfile.php
```

But Apache returns the PHP script itself without interpreting it with its File argument.

Does anyone have an idea to do this?
Thank you,

Comment: Since this is about apache _configuration_, it might fit better (and attract more answers) in http://serverfault.com